# Odoo 8: onchange many2one not working

Tags: odoo, onchange, odoo-8, invoice, accounting

under accounting->invoice I'm trying to trigger the onchange uppon selecting a customer(field: partner_id: many2one) from the list , but it fails, whereas adding the onchange decorator on the field "origin" (type: char) works normally. can anybody help?

NB: in Odoo debugging mode the help message shown upon dragging the mouse on customer field that it's binded to an onchange function called: onchange_partner_id(type,...), I wonder if this is the cause of the issue

Here is the code: I inherit from the original invoice model than adding the onchange functions

```
class stock_picking(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice"

#NOT triggered
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def _onchange_customer(self):
    print("debug:y_account_invoice: _onchange_customer:selected")

#triggered successfully    
@api.onchange('origin')
def _onchange_origin(self):
    print("debug:y_account_invoice: _onchange_origin")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to override this method in py.

```
@api.multi
def onchange_partner_id(self, type, partner_id, date_invoice=False, payment_term=False, partner_bank_id=False, company_id=False):
    res = super(classname, self).onchange_partner_id(type, partner_id, date_invoice=date_invoice,payment_term=payment_term, partner_bank_id=partner_bank_id, company_id=company_id)
    #### Update your code 
    # If you want to set any fields value then just simply update it in res and return res
    res['value'].update({'account_id': new_value,})
    return res
```

**onchange_partner_id** is already there you need to override it don't define it again. And **_onchange_origin** working in your case because it's not there already.

Comment: thanks Emipro, this function is triggered upon partner_id changes, but now I got this bug : [ ...return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)  TypeError: onchange_partner_id() got multiple values for keyword argument 'date_invoice'.]. note that Im using Pyhon 2.7, also I verfied the method signature in super class and it's 7 argument. The bug is triggered upon opening a new invoice (parsing the code on default values)

Comment: Can you please show me your code ? it's good if you can add it to the question.

Comment: I did slight mistake I added self in method calling, I have just removed it from super method parameter list, check it now.

Comment: Tech, it works thank you. Note that I'm beginner in Python and excluding the self from arguments list when calling the onchange_partner_id is little bit confusing, whereas the self is declaring in the implementation of this function. However this how Python works!

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative solution to my issue(not ideal). I have overwride the whole function from account_invoice core to my custom module that inherit from it and then added my custom code on it. So that the partner on change function is triggered normally.(omitting the super call)

```
  #overwritten function
  @api.multi
  def onchange_partner_id(self, type, partner_id, date_invoice=False,
        payment_term=False, partner_bank_id=False, company_id=False): 
     #KEEP the Core Code
     #custom code
     #add the sales person to the result in case it was not False
     if user_id_sales_per != False:
        print("Debug:account.invoice.onchange_partner_id(): my custom code")
```

Comment: It's always advisable to call super because you never know from how many places that method will be called so try to avoid to completely override unless it's necessary. Because you think that you have already added it's base code in your function but it will never pass ahead and it will break that execution channel.